# Activity is grayed out after 'coming back'

Tags: android, android-activity, onpause

I have this really weird problem with Android Activities.
Whenever I 'return' to an activity, it is 'grayed out' and not touchable.
Like there would be an invisible dialog on top of it.

by 'return' I mean:

- I either start a new activity and press the Back-button to come back to the previous one
- or just press the Home-button and then hold the Home-button until the recent Apps show up and then select my app again

After pressing the Back-Button, 'the gray' goes away and I can use the activity again just fine...
but it's still rather strange and annoying

I have no real explanation for it.

I'm guessing something happens "onPause"...
but I havn't even overwritten this method in my activity.

Comment: Show us some code snippet so that we can see what's wrong

Comment: I wouldn't know where exactly to cut those snippets out from
it's a rather long class, and I'm not really sure which functions are critical for this problem - as I'm not really sure what exactly the problem is :)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't overridden onPause, how about onResume, onStart, onStop, or onRestart?

From what you've said, the most likely problem are would be onResume.  Are you overriding anything in your activities base classes?

My guess is that you are trying to display some sort of debug dialog and it is getting triggered in the onResume.

Also, are you trying to do anything with styles?

Comment: I actually haven't over-written any of those methos
not onStop, notStart, not onResume.....nothing

I don't really know where this 'dialog' would come from